# what are the guidelines when writing cucumber stories?

Tags: java, cucumber

What are the guidelines that need to be followed while writing cucumber stories.

When to use @Given @when @Then @and tags?

Comment: [This](http://blog.codeship.com/cucumber-best-practices/) may be useful, not sure how related it is though.

Answer (score 2):

Given is for a step that sets up the test. When is for a step that triggers the test. Then is for a step that verifies the criteria/results of the test. And is to extend any of the previous Given/When/Then steps.

Comment: maybe it should be mentioned that it is only for human readibility, it doesnt really matter which tag you are using if you view it from the programms side.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, cucumber uses [`.feature`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Feature-Introduction) files to express software behavior in a human-readable format.  Here's a contrived example:

```
Feature: Login Page
  As a user, I want to login

  Scenario: Successfully login
    Given I am on the login page
    And I enter a valid password
    When I press the login button
    Then I should be logged-in
```

The [`Given/When/Then`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Given-When-Then) steps from the scenarios in the feature files are then mapped to [step definitions](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Definitions).  For example:

```
Given /^I am on the login page$/ do
  # your code here
end
```

Within the step definitions, you can use your language of choice to execute the step.  Admittedly, this is a superficial explanation, and I'd advise digging in on the documentation.

Comment: If this helped, you can accept the answer (which helps keep SO tidy).